# Android Google Places API - PlaceAutocompleteFragment clear button listener

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-maps-android-api-2, android-location, google-places

I am using [Google Places API for Android - PlaceAutocompleteFragment](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/)  API in my project to search locations,  when user selects a location then get the records using location lat-long and display it to ListView. 
Now the problem is whenever user taps on **clear button (X)** of [PlaceAutocompleteFragment](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/ui/PlaceAutocompleteFragment) I want clear ListView items for which I need to listen to clear button onClick? How to do that?
[image]
Any help will be appreciated.

```
autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
        LatLng latLng=place.getLatLng();
        //hit web service, response parsing and add it to listview.
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Status status) {
        Log.i(TAG, "An error occurred: " + status);
    }
});
```

Comment: try removing that item from arraylist you setting to adapter and then call notifyDataSetChanged(). For more Please post code

Comment: @JagjitSingh I know how to clear listview items.. brefore that I need to listen to close button click of PlaceAutocompleteFragment ... I don't find any method for this api.

Comment: Post whole code for that.

Comment: you dont have object of the placeautocomplete . you just fire an intent and thats it. the control goes into that fragment. so you can not have any listener for this. remember you have a onactivityresult for this. in my opnion there is no method for this.

Comment: @JagjitSingh added more code.. I don't think HttpRequest, Response parsing code needed as its working fine.. The only main thing is set up onclick listener for clearn/close button of PlaceAutocompleteFragment.

Comment: @SagarNayak thats true, I understand that but isn't it obvious that whenever we click clear, we need clear items of that result also. :)

Comment: places api does not provide you with such method.

are you using autocomplete or the fragment provided by google .?

Comment: what yes ? autocomplete or google fragment ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106909/discussion-between-bharat-and-sagar-nayak).

Comment: @SagarNayak autocomplete..

Comment: @SagarNayak got a solution.. check my answer... no need to setup manual location search..

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Looking at the source code of `PlaceAutocompleteFragment` I found those view ids and setup a `onClickListener` like this:

```
autocompleteFragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.place_autocomplete_clear_button)
    .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // example : way to access view from PlaceAutoCompleteFragment
            // ((EditText) autocompleteFragment.getView()
            // .findViewById(R.id.place_autocomplete_search_input)).setText(""); 
            autocompleteFragment.setText("");
            view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
});
```

Comment: Hi ,can we get the access of edittext of searchview used in PlaceAutocompleteFragment if we call it using IntentBuilder

Comment: @NancyY using this `id` you can get searchview edittext `R.id.place_autocomplete_search_input`

Comment: Why don't you just autocompleteFragment.setText("");

Comment: @dvdciri because you dont have a method setText for AutoCompleteFragment.

Comment: It does have it, look at the documentation https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/ui/PlaceAutocompleteFragment

Comment: Great detective work and answer.  Wish I could upvote more than once.

Comment: @Bharatesh How did you look at the source code? I don't seem able to find it.

Comment: @Bharatesh can you write google's default codes for search input onClick like in the answer?

Comment: @ninbit do you mean search input (edittext) listener?

Comment: @Mox can you check through sdk/library files or open the file within studio.

Comment: @Bharatesh yes. I want to add a listener for that edittext (R.id.place_autocomplete_search_input). If I add only with my needings, then the box is not working

Comment: @ninbit if doubt default behavior(getting search result) will work if you override edittext listener as you provided your own listeners. Can you check what android is doing when edittext changes. Check the source code you might find something.

Comment: @Bharatesh as you explain the problem is this: when I override the listener, the autocomplete just not working, even not triggered for typing. Is it possible to call the default listener with a method like 'super' keyword?

Comment: @ninbit I doubt

Comment: does anyone have this done in Kotlin? im having trouble with the `findViewById` requiring a Type inference for `R.id.place_autocomplete_clear_button`

Comment: Hi all, In latest version, the id of the view is changed to "R.id.places_autocomplete_clear_button", kindly change it.

Comment: For those who can't find `R.id.places_autocomplete_clear_button`, instead try using: `com.google.android.libraries.places.R.id.places_autocomplete_search_input`

Comment: change places_autocomplete_clear_button instead of place_autocomplete_clear_button. For me the "s" was the problem

Answer (score 0):

The answer above did not solve my problem.
I could solve it with a trick :)

```
    autocompleteFragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.place_autocomplete_clear_button).setPadding(0,0,0,55555);
```

Answer (score 0):

I create the `findViewById` in the `onCreate` of the activity, I was getting the following error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
```

Because the fragment is not initialized/visible yet. I moved the listener inside the `setOnPlaceSelectedListener` and it's working fine now.

```
autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
        homeAddressPlaceID = place.getId();
        Log.i(TAG, "Place: " + place.getName() + ", " + place);

        autocompleteFragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.places_autocomplete_clear_button)
                .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        autocompleteFragment.setText("");
                        homeAddressPlaceID = "";
                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Status status) {
        Log.i(TAG, "An error occurred: " + status);
    }
});
```